# Gradient Boosted machine in python

Tags: python, search, grid, roc, gbm

I am trying to use gradient boosted machine(gbm) in python to my model report

I wrote some codes to perform the task but I was getting an error message

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(ml_Telco.drop(labels=['Churn'],axis=1),
                                               ml_Telco['Churn'],
                                               test_size=0.3,
                                               random_state=0)
target = 'Churn'
x_train.shape,x_test.shape

def modelfit(alg, dtrain, predictors, performCV=True,printFeatureImportance=True, cv_folds=5):
    #Fit the algorithm on the data
    alg.fit(dtrain[predictors], dtrain['Churn'])    
    #Predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(dtrain[predictors])
    dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(dtrain[predictors])[:,1]
    #Perform cross-validation:
    if performCV:
        cv_score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg,dtrain[predictors],dtrain['Churn'], cv=cv_folds, scoring='roc_auc')

    #Print model report:
    print ("\nModel Report")
    print ("Accuracy : %.4g" % metrics.accuracy_score(dtrain['Churn'].values,dtrain_predictions))

    print( "AUC Score (Train): %f" % metrics.roc_auc_score(dtrain['Churn'],dtrain_predprob))   
    if performCV:
        print( "CV Score : Mean - %.7g | Std - %.7g | Min - %.7g | Max %.7g" % (np.mean(cv_score),np.std(cv_score),np.min(cv_score),np.max(cv_score)))        
    #Print Feature Importance:
    if printFeatureImportance:
        feat_imp = pd.Series(alg.feature_importances_,predictors).sort_values(ascending=False)
        feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances')
        plt.ylabel('Feature Importance Score')

predictors = [x for x in x_train.columns if x not in ['Churn']]
gbm0 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=10)
modelfit(gbm0, x_train, predictors)
```

I expected to get a model report showing:
Accuracy
Auc Score(train)
CV Score

But I got the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-154-2ee19dd7c558> in <module>

      1 predictors = [x for x in x_train.columns if x not in ['Churn']]

      2 gbm0 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=10)

----> 3 modelfit(gbm0, x_train, predictors)

KeyError: 'Churn'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your function `modelfit` is expecting a data frame `dtrain`, which should have all columns including your y-variable column 'churn'. so concatenate `x_train` and `y_train` first and then pass the resulting data frame to  `modelfit` function

```
df=pd.concat([x_train, y_train], axis=1)
gbm0 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=10)
modelfit(gbm0, df, x_train.columns)
```

Here in your `model fit` function , you are fitting the model and predicting on same data set, i.e., your training set(x_train,ytrain). Ideally you should be fitting the model to your training set and predict on your test set (x_test,y_test).